# How do I add objects to an ArrayList while the program is running?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm not using anything that saves permanent changes, so when the program ends, the ArrayList is also reset. Now, when the program runs, a user will enter two values. Those values will be used in the creation of a class object, and said object will be assigned to an array index. Here's that code below:

```
System.out.print("\nEnter a name of your choosing: ");
sName = s.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nPlease enter a password: ");
sPass = s.nextLine();
Customer c = new Customer(sName, "", sName, sPass, 0, 0);
for (int x = 0; x < customers.size(); x++) {
     if (x == customers.size()) {
         customers.add(x, c);
     }
}
return;
```

ArrayList statement, if it helps.

```
static ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList();
```

The values for "Customer c" besides 'sName' and 'sPass' are not important in this context. The idea here is that when a person registers a new customer account, this register function can be used indefinitely. (ex: entering "David", "monkey1" will be customers[0]. Entering "Amy", "turtles4ever" will be customers[1]).

Within the for loop, I added that it will only be added to customers[] if 'x' is equal to the max array size, which  can be found with '.size()'. This way, the object **won't** just overwrite all the previous array values.

Despite all that, for some reason, nothing happens. Debugging shows that there is *nothing* in the element. Or the array for that matter. It should also be noted that doing the customer.add() statement outside the for-loop works just fine.

I'm pretty sure this happens because there's nothing in the Customer ArrayList (it's empty), so it kinda just does nothing when the for-loop starts. I could just reverse the logic, but I don't feel that's right solution to this problem. In conclusion, I'm stuck.

Comment: You make it too complicated. In the for loop, `x < customers.size()` will always fail, because there are no elements in there yet. So instead of the whole `for` loop (all 5 lines), write that one line: `customers.add(c);`. `ArrayList` automatically increases its size, you will NOT overwrite anything in there if you simply call `.add(obj)`, because that will ALWAYS be inserted as the last element.